# How to select data with overdue dates? Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to select data which has an overdue dates.
For example,
Deadline is 9-9-2016 and the date today is 10-10-2016.
Clearly 9-9-2016 is already overdue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try to use [NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) function in `where` clause to check overdue dates. Somethisn like this:

```
select * from your_table where your_date < NOW()
```

Also you can try use `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in MySql. Depending on the type of your column, you may want to use something like `CURRENT_DATE()` or `CURRENT_TIME()`:

```
select * from mytable where mydate < CURRENT_DATE()
```